# Error 406 in a simple request using Spring 3 and Jackson 1.9

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I've create a simple test case with Jackson 1.9 and Spring 3. My goal was to test how easy was to use both of them to generate JSON results. My problem is that I get an error 406

So far, it seems that you only need to configure Spring and the code is really straightforward . My Spring configuration file is just:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.goldengecko" />
<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

And my controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestsController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/tests", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Item getBooks() {
        return new Item();
    }
}
```

The Item class is just:

```
public class Item {
    private String name;

    public Item() {
        name = "Test name";
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void setName( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

I made sure I added the jackson-core-asl.jar and jackson-mapper-asl.jar.

From everything I read, it's just that: you don't seem to need to worry about setting a content-accepted in the request, just open a normal Chrome browser and request that service.

That's where I get a 406.

I created a simple jQuery getJSON call, with the same result.

Do you know what can be wrong? So far there are few things to fail: the code seems to be the right approach and the Jackson files required by Spring are there.

Comment: Did you try adding the accept header (text/json)?  Also do you have any other DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping bean in your context?

Answer (score -1):

Per section 10.4.7 at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html:

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.
>
> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field. Depending upon the format and the capabilities of the user agent, selection of the most appropriate choice MAY be performed automatically. However, this specification does not define any standard for such automatic selection.
>
> > Note: HTTP/1.1 servers are allowed to return responses which are not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request. In some cases, this may even be preferable to sending a 406 response. User agents are encouraged to inspect the headers of an incoming response to determine if it is acceptable.
>
> If the response could be unacceptable, a user agent SHOULD temporarily stop receipt of more data and query the user for a decision on further actions.

So it sounds like perhaps you do need to set the acceptable content types on the receiving side.